# Is there a way to force update redux-form's submitting prop?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-form, invisible-recaptcha

I'm using reCAPTCHA v2 on a sign-up form using redux-form. When the user clicks submit the reCAPTCHA modal pops up and the redux-form's `submitting` prop goes from `false` to `true` and we disable the submit button. If the user closes the reCAPTCHA modal before completing it, the submit button remains disabled and the user can not get the modal to pop back up. Is there any way to force update the `submitting` prop back to `false` if the user closes the modal before completing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an action creator for this purpose:

[**`stopSubmit(form:String, errors:Object)`**](https://redux-form.com/8.2.2/docs/api/actioncreators.md/#-code-stopsubmit-form-string-errors-object-code-)

For example:

```js
...
import { stopSubmit } from 'redux-form';
...

...
dispatch(stopSubmit('formName', {}));
...
```